# HTML PHP Help Form

Tags: php, html

I'm trying my best to generate a unique link with the following information from ID1 and ID2. I've even tested with echo and paste the following .html to the server and there weren't any respond and also tried it with echo also nothing.

I need help basically , thank you.

```
    <form method="post" action="">

    <h1 style="color:#0CF; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Enter ID 1:</h1>

    <input type="text" value="" name ="cid" id="cid" />

    <h1 style="color:#0CF; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Enter ID 2:</h1>

    <input type="text" value="" name ="gid" id="gid"/>


<h1 style="color:#0CF; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Copy Your Link     Here</h1>
<textarea style="width:500px; height:50px;"></textarea><br /><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit"/>

        </form>

    <?php               

$cid = $_POST["cid"];
$gid = $_POST["gid"];


        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {

        //I want to make a new link $url = "www.something.com/" together with the combination of ID 1 and ID2 .

    Example : www.something.com/ID1+ID2 // I want like this if its possible

    }
    else               
    {
        echo "You've failed";
    }

    ?>

I need help if you don't mind
```

Comment: @KevinAbelita , its in html so i'm just adding a php file inside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form method="post" action="">

    <h1 style="color:#0CF; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Enter ID 1:</h1>

    <input type="text" value="" name ="cid" id="cid" />

    <h1 style="color:#0CF; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Enter ID 2:</h1>

    <input type="text" value="" name ="gid" id="gid"/>


<h1 style="color:#0CF; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Copy Your Link     Here</h1>
<textarea style="width:500px; height:50px;"></textarea><br /><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit"/>

        </form>

    <?php               




        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {
      $cid = $_POST["cid"];
     $gid = $_POST["gid"];

        //I want to make a new link $url = "www.something.com/" together with the combination of ID 1 and ID2 .

    $emp  = "Example : www.something.com/".$cid.$gid // I want like this if its possible

    }
    else               
    {
        echo "You've failed";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: how your answer is different from mine ?

Comment: you can see some difference in my answer.

Comment: @user3522137 , Yeah . Your answer is different . Is there anyway i can add the result emp into the textarea where it mentioned copy link from here.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php       
$new_link = ""; 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    if(isset($_POST['cid'],$_POST['gid']))
    {
        $cid = $_POST['cid'];
        $gid = $_POST['gid'];
        $new_link = "www.something.com/".$cid.$gid;

           // if your input is integer and you want to add them then use this
           // $new_link = "www.something.com/".($cid+$gid);

    }
}

?>


<form method="post" action="">
     <h1 style="color:#0CF; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Enter ID 1:</h1>
        <input type="text" value="" name ="cid" id="cid" />
     <h1 style="color:#0CF; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Enter ID 2:</h1>
        <input type="text" value="" name ="gid" id="gid"/>

    <h1 style="color:#0CF; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Copy Your Link     Here</h1>
        <textarea style="width:500px; height:50px;"><?php echo $new_link;?></textarea><br /><br /><br />

   <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit"/>

</form>
```

Comment: Why the double `if` ? Why not just `if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['cid'],$_POST['gid']))` ?

Comment: I tried uploading to the server the textarea is showing this "<?php echo $new_link;?>" and the result is not appearing.

Comment: ya it can be write as combine. nothing for special reason just for understanding.

Comment: is this your php file?

Comment: @SatishSharma , yeah . I had to choice since the HTTP_Build_Query is kinda hard for me to generate link .